# Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I have a service with a basichttp binding and I am trying to add a net.tcp binding to it. here is how the config looks like:

```
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Some.L.E.S.BusinessService">


        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IBusinessService"
          contract="Some.L.E.Services.IBusinessService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint> 


        <endpoint address="/BusinessService.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding_IBusinessService" contract="Some.L.E.Services.IBusinessService">
              <identity>
                  <dns value="localhost" />
              </identity>
          </endpoint>


          <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                 <add baseAddress="http://localhost:63487/"/> 
                 <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/" />
              </baseAddresses>
          </host>


      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
            <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <!-- Start of HostServices client configurations -->
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IBusinessService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>

 </basicHttpBinding>
        <!-- RSF -->
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="netTcpBinding_IBusinessService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            transferMode="Buffered">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
     maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                </security>
            </binding> 
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

I start this service up in VS2010 and I am trying to connect to it from another VS2010 project. However I get the following error:

Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]

Most solutions seem to recommend changes to the web.config in IIS virtual directory. But my Service is not hosted in IIS.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,

GM

Comment: You have no port specified on net.tcp baseAddress.

Comment: facing the same issue. Did you find the solution?